# Running javascript only if php condition is met

Tags: javascript, php, if-statement

How do you run javascript if only a php condition is met? I am trying to show a pop-up only if `$page_count` is `<= 1`. The php is fine and runs correctly as I have tested it with simple echos, it is only when I try to negate the javascript from running if the `$page_count` is over 2 that this still runs.

Is there a common method to go about this?

```
if ($page_count <= 1) {
    $setup_popup =
    '<div id="status-popup">
        <div id="status-popup-container" class="total-center">
            <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">Close</a>
        </div>
    </div>'
    ;
}
else {
    $setup_popup = NULL;
}
```

Javascript

```
$('#status-popup').fadeIn(350);

$('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
    var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
    $('#status-popup').fadeOut(350);
    $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
     e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Why not just pass the counter as a variable and let the JS decide?

Comment: How can js runs if you don't have `status-popup` on a page?

Comment: @ssube Not sure how to.

Comment: Sorry everyone, I used the wrong php variable. Your solutions did help me, so I am sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1):

As the commenters suggested, something as simple as:

```
if(document.getElementById('status-popup')){
    $('#status-popup').fadeIn(350);

    $('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
        var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
        $('#status-popup').fadeOut(350);
        $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
         e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

should do it.

You could also enclose the javascript inside a PHP if statement if necessary:

```
<?php
if ($page_count <= 1) {
?>
        $('#status-popup').fadeIn(350);

        $('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
            var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
            $('#status-popup').fadeOut(350);
            $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
             e.preventDefault();
        });
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: The first solution did not help. I will try the second.

Answer (score 1):

I would always add the modal elements, but include the counter and let JS do the logic:

```
<script type="application/javascript">
var pageCounter = <?php $page_count ?>;
if (pageCounter) {
  $('#status-popup').fadeIn(350);

  $('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
    var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
    $('#status-popup').fadeOut(350);
    $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
     e.preventDefault();
  });
}
</script>
<div id="status-popup">
  <div id="status-popup-container" class="total-center">
    <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">Close</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

No magic, little complexity, and you can change or test the value from the client as well as from the server (which allows little things like unit testing, AJAX, etc).

Comment: So would I just set the pageCounter condition to =< 1 `if (pageCounter =< 1) {` ?

Comment: You can change the `if (pageCounter)` to any condition you would like.

Comment: Wouldn't this solution always leave the static html present? I only want the html to be visible if the condition is met.

Answer (score 1):

PHP code is executed by server than it's result is transmited to the client so you could do :

```
if ($page_count <= 1) {
    $setup_popup = "";
    if ($page_count >=2 ) {
        $setup_popup .= "<script type="text/javascript">[put your js code here]</script>";
    }
    $setup_popup .= '<div id="status-popup">
        <div id="status-popup-container" class="total-center">
            <a class="popup-close" data-popup-close="popup-1" href="#">Close</a>
        </div>
    </div>';
}
else {
    $setup_popup = NULL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var page_count = <?= $page_count ?>;

if(page_count <= 1) {
    $('#status-popup').fadeIn(350);
    $('[data-popup-close]').on('click', function(e)  {
        var targeted_popup_class = jQuery(this).attr('data-popup-close');
        $('#status-popup').fadeOut(350);
        $('body').css('overflow', 'auto');
         e.preventDefault();
    });
}
```

You don't need to use `else` condition since you're only going to show the popup when the page count is less than 2. Hope it works.